# Is there a way to assign an html ID automatically to a field in a content type?

Tags: 7, javascript

I am using **JavaScript** in my **custom module** and the field is inside an div, but that div only has a class tag.  Is there a way to automatically give an **ID** to the **field** so that whenever it shows up, it's easier to manipulate it with an **ID** tag?  The field belongs to a content type.

Comment: Almost certainly "yes", but no possible way to tell you how until you provide more info...

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Clive, what more info do you want?  I want it so whenever the field is generated, there's an automatically generated HTML tag ID so it's easier to grab it when using JavaScript. The field is inside of a content type

Comment: Sorry, poorly phrased - it's all conditional info as-it-were (are you using anything that currently overrides field templates? What theme are you using? Do you want to auto-add an ID for every single field, or do you want to target a specific field or fields? stuff like that)

Comment: I don't believe I am using anything that overrides field templates,  we have a custom theme, and the danland theme.  I only want to auto-add an ID for a certain field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was only displaying the content with a view, in the view settings
- I edited the specific field 
 
- clicked **REWRITE RESULTS** 
- checked "Rewrite the the output of this field" 
- and wrote:

`<p id="file-types"> [field_file_type_text] </p>`

This solved the problem

Comment: That's a good solution - there are also programmatic ways to do it if you're not in the context of a view, I'll try and throw some code in an answer later as an example

Comment: Great, thanks a lot @Clive.  I really appreciate the help.